# Unable to have a variable be set a value inside of a foreach loop (the variable had been declared before it). C#

Tags: c#, foreach, variable-assignment

```
int PositionEvaluation = 0;
Move FirstDepth;
Move SecondDepth;

foreach (Move move in FirstDepthMoves)
{
    // Try a move
    board.MakeMove(move);
         
    Move[] SecondDepthMoves = board.GetLegalMoves();

    foreach (Move move1 in SecondDepthMoves)
    {
        // Try a second move
        board.MakeMove(move1);
                
        int CurrentEvaluation1 = EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite);

        // If move be good, then we memorize it
        if (CurrentEvaluation1 > PositionEvaluation)
        {
            // Record this to then play + for seeing its thinking process in Console
            FirstDepth = move;
            SecondDepth = move1;

            PositionEvaluation = CurrentEvaluation1;
        }
           
        board.UndoMove(move1);
    }
        
    board.UndoMove(move);
}

// Here it tells me that it didn't get the value assigned to FirstDepth and SecondDepth from foreach loop
// Idk what to do else about it
Console.WriteLine(FirstDepth);

board.MakeMove(FirstDepth);
Console.WriteLine(EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite));

Console.WriteLine(SecondDepth);
board.MakeMove(SecondDepth);
Console.WriteLine(EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite));

board.UndoMove(SecondDepth); 
board.UndoMove(FirstDepth);
```

In the code above I declare a variable before a foreach loop, and then in that for each loop it is assigned the desired value. But there where I try to write it to console, as well as make a move with it, it is telling me it is unassigned.

I had tried setting a value for the variable before it, but that just kept that value without changing it:

```
Move FirstDepth = moveToPlay;
Move SecondDepth = moveToPlay;
```

I had also tried to set a temporary value to get it, but it also didn't work.

For more context, this is part of my attempt at a tiny chess bot contest which was created by SebLeague. Here is a link to it: https://github.com/SebLague/Chess-Challenge

Here is full file of MyBot:

```
using ChessChallenge.API;
using System;

public class MyBot : IChessBot
{
    const PieceType Pawn = (PieceType)1;
    const PieceType Knight = (PieceType)2;
    const PieceType Bishop = (PieceType)3;
    const PieceType Rook = (PieceType)4;
    const PieceType Queen = (PieceType)5;

    public Move Think(Board board, Timer timer)
    {
        bool IsBotWhite = board.IsWhiteToMove;
        Move[] FirstDepthMoves = board.GetLegalMoves();

        Random rng = new();
        Move moveToPlay = FirstDepthMoves[rng.Next(FirstDepthMoves.Length)];
        int PositionEvaluation = 0;

        Move FirstDepth = moveToPlay;
        Move SecondDepth = moveToPlay;

        foreach (Move move in FirstDepthMoves)
        {
            //Try a move
            board.MakeMove(move);

            FirstDepth = moveToPlay;
            SecondDepth = moveToPlay;
            
            Move[] SecondDepthMoves = board.GetLegalMoves();

            foreach (Move move1 in SecondDepthMoves)
            {
                // Try a second move
                board.MakeMove(move1);
                    
                int CurrentEvaluation1 = EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite);
                // If move be good, then we memorize it
                if (CurrentEvaluation1 > PositionEvaluation)
                {
                    //Record this to then play + for seeing its thinking process in Console
                    FirstDepth = move;
                    SecondDepth = move1;

                    PositionEvaluation = CurrentEvaluation1;
                }
               
                board.UndoMove(move1);
            }
            
            board.UndoMove(move);
        }

        // Here it tells me that It didnt get the value assigned to FirstDepth and SecondDepth from foreach loop
        //Idk what to do else about it
        Console.WriteLine(FirstDepth);
        board.MakeMove(FirstDepth);
        Console.WriteLine(EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite));
        Console.WriteLine(SecondDepth);
        board.MakeMove(SecondDepth);
        Console.WriteLine(EvaluatePosition(board, !IsBotWhite));
        board.UndoMove(SecondDepth); 
        board.UndoMove(FirstDepth);
        return FirstDepth;
    }
    
    int EvaluatePosition(Board board, bool IsWhite)
    {
        //the E stands for Enemy
        PieceList Pawns = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Pawn, white: IsWhite);
        PieceList Knights = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Knight, white: IsWhite);
        PieceList Bishops = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Bishop, white: IsWhite);
        PieceList Rooks = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Rook, white: IsWhite);
        PieceList Queens = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Queen, white: IsWhite);

        bool IsWhiteE = !IsWhite;

        PieceList PawnsE = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Pawn, white: IsWhiteE);
        PieceList KnightsE = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Knight, white: IsWhiteE);
        PieceList BishopsE = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Bishop, white: IsWhiteE);
        PieceList RooksE = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Rook, white: IsWhiteE);
        PieceList QueensE = board.GetPieceList(pieceType: Queen, white: IsWhiteE);

        int TotalEval = ((Pawns.Count * 1) + (Knights.Count * 3) + (Bishops.Count * 3) + (Rooks.Count * 5) + (Queens.Count * 9)) - ((PawnsE.Count * 1) + (KnightsE.Count * 3) + (BishopsE.Count * 3) + (RooksE.Count * 5) + (QueensE.Count * 9));

        if (board.IsDraw())
        {
            TotalEval = -100;
        }
        else if (board.IsInCheckmate())
        {
            TotalEval = 100;
        }

        if (board.IsInCheck())
        {
            TotalEval = TotalEval +  1;
        } 
        
        return -TotalEval;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if there are no legal moves or `CurrentEvaluation1 > PositionEvalueation` is always false? The compiler can't be sure.

Comment: They are always legal moves, but it might be that they are not assigned the value properly, I will look into that.

Comment: No, this is not the point. The compiler makes a static analysis based on your code text. When the compiler does this, the application is not running and the variables do not exist in memory yet. so, the compiler does not know which values these variables will have at runtime and thus cannot decide whether `CurrentEvaluation1 > PositionEvalueation` will ever be true. There is a theoretical possibility the the `if`-statement will never be entered and thus, that these variables will never be initialized. This is what the compiler is complaining about.